# Filter source files for custom rule

Tags: bazel

I used a bazel macro to run a python test on a subset of source files. Similar to this:

```
def report(name, srcs):
    source_labels = [file for file in srcs if file.startswith("a")]
    if len(source_labels) == 0:
        return;

    source_filenames = ["$(location %s)" % x for x in source_labels]

    native.py_test(
        name = name + "_report",
        srcs = ["report_tool"],
        data = source_labels,
        main = "report_tool.py",
        args = source_filenames,
    )

report("foo", ["foo.hpp", "afoo.hpp"])
```

This worked fine until one of my source files started using a select and now I get the error:

```
File "/home/david/foo/report.bzl", line 47, in report
    [file for file in srcs if file.startswith("a")]
type 'select' is not iterable
```

I tried to move the code to a bazel rule, but then I get a different error that py_test can not be used in the analysis phase.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that the `select` is causing the error is that macros are evaluated during the loading phase, whereas `selects`s are not evaluated until the analysis phase (see [Extension Overview](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html)).

Similarly, `py_test` can't be used in a rule implementation because the rule implementation is evaluated in the analysis phase, whereas the `py_test` would need to have been loaded in the loading phase.

One way past this is to create a separate Starlark rule that takes a list of labels and just creates a file with each filename from the label. Then the `py_test` takes that file as data and loads the other files from there. Something like this:

```py
def report(name, srcs):

  file_locations_label = "_" + name + "_file_locations"
  _generate_file_locations(
    name = file_locations_label,
    labels = srcs
  )

  native.py_test(
      name = name + "_report",
      srcs = ["report_tool.py"],
      data = srcs + [file_locations_label],
      main = "report_tool.py",
      args = ["$(location %s)" % file_locations_label]
  )


def _generate_file_locations_impl(ctx):
  paths = []
  for l in ctx.attr.labels:
    f = l.files.to_list()[0]
    if f.basename.startswith("a"):
      paths.append(f.short_path)
  ctx.actions.write(ctx.outputs.file_paths, "\n".join(paths))
  return DefaultInfo(runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = [ctx.outputs.file_paths]))

_generate_file_locations = rule(
  implementation = _generate_file_locations_impl,
  attrs = { "labels": attr.label_list(allow_files = True) },
  outputs = { "file_paths": "%{name}_files" },
)
```

This has one disadvantage: Because the `py_test` has to depend on all the sources, the `py_test` will get rerun even if the only files that have changed are the ignored files. (If this is a significant drawback, then there is at least one way around this, which is to have _generate_file_locations filter the files too, and have the `py_test` depend on only _generate_file_locations. This could maybe be accomplished through [runfiles symlinks](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/ctx.html#runfiles))

Update:

Since the test report tool comes from an external repository and can't be easily modified, here's another approach that might work better. Rather than create a rule that creates a params file (a file containing the paths to process) as above, the Starlark rule can itself be a test rule that uses the report tool as the test executable:

```py
def _report_test_impl(ctx):
  filtered_srcs = []
  for f in ctx.attr.srcs:
    f = f.files.to_list()[0]
    if f.basename.startswith("a"):
      filtered_srcs.append(f)

  report_tool = ctx.attr._report_test_tool
  ctx.actions.write(
      output = ctx.outputs.executable,
      content = "{report_tool} {paths}".format(
          report_tool = report_tool.files_to_run.executable.short_path,
          paths = " ".join([f.short_path for f in filtered_srcs]))
  )

  runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = filtered_srcs).merge(
      report_tool.default_runfiles)
  return DefaultInfo(runfiles = runfiles)

report_test = rule(
  implementation = _report_test_impl,
  attrs = {
      "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files = True),
      "_report_test_tool": attr.label(default="//:report_test_tool"),
  },
  test = True,
)
```

This requires that the test report tool be a `py_binary` somewhere so that the test rule above can depend on it:

```py
py_binary(
    name = "report_test_tool",
    srcs = ["report_tool.py"],
    main = "report_tool.py",
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried to make it work with your suggestions, however now my python scripts gets called with the arguments ['foo/_foo_file_locations_files'] instead of a list of filenames..

Comment: That file (foo/_foo_file_locations_files) will contain the file paths to use. It's one level of indirection: you're using the intermediate _generate_file_locations rule to evaluate the select. Then that rule puts the file names into a file. Your python script can then read the file to know what other files to read.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a very clean solution as the Python script comes from an external dependency.. Is there not way to "return" a list of filtered targets in bazel?

Comment: There's another approach that might work better for you, I'll update my answer

Comment: I went with your original approach and applied a sed command via a genrule so that the external script can work with a file of filenames. It did the job so far, so thank you for your original answer. I'll try the updated solution in the new year.